# if $u(x,y) $ satisfies $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ then $v=u(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$ satisfies $v_{xx} + v_{yy} = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

> if $u(x,y) $ satisfies $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ then
>    $v=u(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$ satisfies $v_{xx} + v_{yy} = 0$

I tried using the chain rule and it didn't work for me.. I think I might have missed something maybe.. 
Could anyone show how to properly write $v_{xx} $ and $v_{yy} $ ?

Thanks.

EDIT : 
my question is also about generally differentiating such function, like is that okay to do :

let $t =\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $s=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$
$v_{x } = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}    $

or if $v$ is just substituting any $x$ in $u$ for $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} $ and any $y$ in $u$ for $\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ then maybe $v_{x } = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}  $

Comment: @MartinR could you please explain the change of equation when he substituted $X$ for $Rcos(\alpha)$ and $Y$ for $Rsin(\alpha)$?

Comment: What you have written in the first two lines of your edit is, letting $t$ and $s$ denote the first and second arguments of $u$, is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mattos could you please explain how is this true : more specifically how did he derive the new equation?$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Y^2}=0 \to
\begin{cases} 
X=R\cos(a)\\
Y=R\sin(a)\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial R^2}+\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}+ \frac{1}{R^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}=0
\end{cases}$$ on the answer that was attached

Comment: It's the Laplacian in polar coordinates. I'm sure if you Google that you will find everything you need. In saying that, you can just do the original question the way you wrote in your edit.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $g:\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to\Bbb R^2,\ (x,y)\mapsto (\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$. Now consider the polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$ instead of the cartesian coordinates $$(x,y)=(r\cos(\varphi),r\sin(\varphi)).$$
Using these, $g$ has the following simple form
$$g(r,\varphi)=\left(\frac{r\cos(\varphi)}{(r\cos(\varphi))^2+(r\sin(\varphi))^2},\frac{r\sin(\varphi)}{(r\cos(\varphi))^2+(r\sin(\varphi))^2}\right)=\left(\frac{\cos(\varphi)}{r},\frac{\sin(\varphi)}{r}\right).$$
Expressing the result also in polar coordinates (whence expressing $g$ completely in polar coordinates) gives
$$g(r,\varphi)=\left(\frac 1r,\varphi\right).$$
The Laplace operator in polar coordinates is given by (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)) 
\begin{align}
[2]:\Delta f(r,\varphi):=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}(r,\varphi)+\frac1r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,\varphi)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \varphi^2}(r,\varphi)
\end{align}
which gives zero by our assumption (your $u$ is my $f$; sorry for that). We want to show that $\Delta(f\circ g)=0$. Thus, we have to show $$\frac{\partial^2(f\circ g)}{\partial r^2}+\frac1r\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2(f\circ g)}{\partial \varphi^2}=0.$$
Using $\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial\varphi}$ where $g=(g_1,g_2)$ and similar for $\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial\varphi}$ we obtain
$$\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial r}(r,\varphi)=-\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(\frac1r,\varphi)\\
\frac{\partial^2 (f\circ g)}{\partial r^2}(r,\varphi)=\frac1{r^4}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}(\frac1r,\varphi)+\frac2{r^3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(\frac1r,\varphi)\\
\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial\varphi}(r,\varphi)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}(r,\varphi).$$
So we have to prove that $$\frac1{r^4}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}(\frac1r,\varphi)+\frac2{r^3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(\frac1r,\varphi)+\frac1r\left(-\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,\varphi)\right)+\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \varphi}\left(\frac1r,\varphi\right)=0.$$
Multiplying by $r^4$ gives the equivalence to $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}(\frac1r,\varphi)+r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(\frac1r,\varphi)+r^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \varphi}\left(\frac1r,\varphi\right)=0$$
which is
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}(\frac1r,\varphi)+\frac1{\frac1r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(\frac1r,\varphi)+\frac1{\frac1{r^2}}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \varphi}\left(\frac1r,\varphi\right)=0$$
and thus true by [2].